# Problem with a shader when building for macOS in unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, urp

I am completely new to the world of shaders etc. so I am trying to be as specific as I can. I have an application where I use the a shader created by Unity see https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/TilingRandomization that randomises the tiling. In the Editor (I use it on windows) & when building it for Windows it works fine but on Mac something is wrong and I get these random reflections:

[image]

My suscipion is that it has to do with the metal part of the shader but I am completely out of my depth here. When I build the application I get the following warnings corroborating my suspicion:

```
Shader warning in 'Shader Graphs/TilingRandomizationTest_PBRLit_ShaderGraph': 'UnityMetaVertexPosition': implicit truncation of vector type at /Users/Alex/Documents/Work/researchProjects/OLM_project/experiment/unityProjects/Object-Location-Memory-Task/Library/PackageCache/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@12.1.6/Editor/ShaderGraph/Includes/Varyings.hlsl(130) (on metal)

Compiling Subshader: 0, Pass: Meta, Vertex program with DEBUGMODE_NONE UVMODE_UV0
Platform defines: SHADER_API_DESKTOP UNITY_ENABLE_DETAIL_NORMALMAP UNITY_ENABLE_REFLECTION_BUFFERS UNITY_LIGHTMAP_RGBM_ENCODING UNITY_LIGHT_PROBE_PROXY_VOLUME UNITY_PASS_META UNITY_PBS_USE_BRDF1 UNITY_SPECCUBE_BLENDING UNITY_SPECCUBE_BOX_PROJECTION UNITY_USE_DITHER_MASK_FOR_ALPHABLENDED_SHADOWS
Disabled keywords: DEBUGMODE_DISABLERANDOM DEBUGMODE_HEXBLENDS DEBUGMODE_RANDOMSEED EDITOR_VISUALIZATION SHADER_API_GLES30 UNITY_ASTC_NORMALMAP_ENCODING UNITY_COLORSPACE_GAMMA UNITY_ENABLE_NATIVE_SHADOW_LOOKUPS UNITY_FRAMEBUFFER_FETCH_AVAILABLE UNITY_HALF_PRECISION_FRAGMENT_SHADER_REGISTERS UNITY_HARDWARE_TIER1 UNITY_HARDWARE_TIER2 UNITY_HARDWARE_TIER3 UNITY_LIGHTMAP_DLDR_ENCODING UNITY_LIGHTMAP_FULL_HDR UNITY_METAL_SHADOWS_USE_POINT_FILTERING UNITY_NO_DXT5nm UNITY_NO_FULL_STANDARD_SHADER UNITY_NO_SCREENSPACE_SHADOWS UNITY_PBS_USE_BRDF2 UNITY_PBS_USE_BRDF3 UNITY_PRETRANSFORM_TO_DISPLAY_ORIENTATION UNITY_UNIFIED_SHADER_PRECISION_MODEL UNITY_VIRTUAL_TEXTURING UVMODE_WORLDXZ
```

I am using URP with Unity 2021.3.1f1c1.

Edit: I played around with the shader and this problem even seem to occur if I disable the input on the metallic channel.

Edit: This doesn't seem to happen for every texture but it only happens on Mac.